# Overloaded methods in class

Tags: c++

How is this possible in a class. function overloading does not count the return type.

```
DataViewModel* DataViewCtrlBase::GetModel()
{
    return m_model;
}

const DataViewModel* DataViewCtrlBase::GetModel() const
{
    return m_model;
}
```

Comment: Maybe there is another difference between the two?

Comment: the `const` after the function definition is part of the signature so it's a different function

Comment: The standard library is full of these overloads.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`DataViewCtrlBase::GetModel()` has both a non-`const`-qualified and a `const`-qualified overloads. The non-`const` overload will only be called when the current class instance is being accessed from in a non-`const` context.

You can think of these methods as being overloaded like this *(pseudocode)*:

```
DataViewModel* GetModel(DataViewCtrlBase* this) { /* ... */ }             /* (0) */
const DataViewModel* GetModel(const DataViewCtrlBase* this) { /* ... */ } /* (1) */
```

Example:

```
DataViewCtrlBase x;

auto& x_non_const = x;
x_non_const.GetModel(); // Calls (0) | Equivalent to: GetModel(x_non_const)

const auto& x_const = x;
x_const.GetModel();     // Calls (1) | Equivalent to: GetModel(x_const)
```